# Splitting funds - How to do it quickly (synched TX)?

Tags: transactions, hardforks, replay-attack

Changing blockchains and synching with Mist is a slow and hacky process so I wondered if there's a more immediate way.

The idea being : transfering funds from my duplicated accounts to new and unique accounts on both sides of the fork in the most synched possible fashion.

Has anyone experienced doing this in an efficient way ?